# Git migration from one server to other by skipping binaries(jar)

Tags: git, migration, binaries

I want to migrate Git repository to new server. But new server has restriction that blocks user from uploading binary files. The old repository contains some jar files. I am ok if these **jar** files wont uploaded to new git repository. I am using below command:

```
git push --mirror new_repo_url
```

How I can migrate this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to checkout the repo locally, then add a `.gitignore` file that excludes `*.jar` and any other binary files that are not allowed. Check that change in locally and then try to push to the new server.

Comment: Hi Adrian, unfortunately this is not working. There are multiple branches. I tried adding git ignore(*.jar) in all the branches but did not work. I need migration because we need history of previous check-ins

Answer (score 0):

You need to first clean the binaries out of your history in a local copy of your git repository.

1. Clone a bare repository locally, `git clone --bare <URL>`
2. Use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to make a clean copy of the repository ignoring the JAR files
3. Clone your clean repository locally to check the results
4. Push the clean repository to the new host